# Why is this c++ code not working - const reference error while trying to delete an element in a set

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ and trying to delete something out of map. In this map is a key of T and a set of Nodes. There is an error related to "const" but I can't figure out how to solve it properly.

I think the relevant error message is this: "/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:868:23: error: passing ‘const Node >’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]"

I played with std::pair and also tried to copy the set out and modify it but that didn't work.

I want to loop the map and check the set if there is a Node n (parameter) and remove it.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
void removeFromAdjacenceList(Node<T> n) {
    //std::map<T, std::set<Node<T>>> adjazenzliste;
    for (auto it = this->adjazenzliste.begin(); it != this->adjazenzliste.end(); ++it) {
        it->second.erase(std::remove(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), n), it->second.end());
    }

}
```

Comment: that's not a complete example, the problem here is somewhere else.. e.g. in declaration of this class, this method, in usage of this template or  in whatever the node is.

Comment: @Swift This question is absolutely legit and the problem can be reproduced with a simple example! No reason to close or down-vote. Actually, this question is quite interesting - I wasn't aware of this issue before.

Comment: @Jodocus  I never downvoted, someone else did, and likely it was downvoted  because working example wasn't provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the erase-remove idiom with associative containers, as stated in the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

> These algorithms cannot be used with associative containers such as
>   `std::set` and `std::map` because *ForwardIt* does not dereference to a
>   *MoveAssignable* type (the keys in these containers are not modifiable)

Fortunately, you do not need the call to `remove` for your use-case anyways. A `set` can only hold unique keys, so you may just call `erase` on the particular key you want to delete from the set.